# Windows 7 show all windows

Tags: windows-7, desktop, gui, compiz

Compiz has a feature called "Show all desktops", usually invoked via `<Super> E`. This shows all the currently open windows.

Windows 7 has something like this (`<Super> Tab`) but the windows are stacked one on top of the other. Is there anything that would allow me to see all the currently open windows and let me select one ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Aero turned on, try   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>   <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

It is like Alt Tab and gives you thumbnail previews.

Another alternative is to download Switcher for Vista, which is a free Expose/Show all windows program.